# getTimeinMillis returns a negative value

Tags: java, android, time

I am making an app which can show time left to some date, and an elapsed time after some date. But I endure some difficulties with dates less than 1970 and bigger than 3300. I have found an explanation why it happens.

> The problem is this sentence from getTimeInMillis:
>   the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.
>   And, as far as i remember, the epoch started on January 1st 1970 you get a negative number for anything before that.

My question is how to solve this problem. (And yes i have heard about JodaTime, I am not allowed to use this library in this app.)

What default(standard) tools should i use?

Here it is a piece of code that does not work properly.

```
private void getDateTime()
{
    Date date = new Date();

    timeRemaining = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(timeRemaining.getTimeInMillis());

    millis = Math.abs(timeRemaining.getTimeInMillis() - targetDate.getTimeInMillis());

    int scnds = (int) (millis / 1000) % 60 ;
    int mnts = (int) ((millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    int hrs = (int) ((millis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    int dys = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    resultDate.setText(getString(R.string.formating, dys, hrs, mnts, scnds));
}
```

Comment: How precise your date should be ? Is it usefull to have milliseconds, seconds, ... I can remember the limits of Calendar but timeImMilllis won't help you. You can easily create your how method to calculate the diff between to MyDate(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

Comment: @AxeIH i can, but it will require additional methods to calculate is a leap year and 28 or 29 days in february. I hope i will find an easier way.

Comment: Well, I could tell you there are API to do it ;-) next problems, your result will reach the same limitation problems.

Comment: @AxelH ok) you've convinced me. I will do it. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by leveraging the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class(es) introduced in `Java 8` --

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime fromDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1914, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0);
    LocalDateTime toDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 12, 16, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(Duration.between(fromDateTime, toDateTime).toMillis());
  }
}
```